# Disabling an input field is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I tried to disable an input field by using disable attribute but it is not working and when I changed the element id and do the disabling by adding the disabled attribute through console it works. can someone please help to resolve this without changing the id??

Comment: I don't believe he actually forgot to share the code. How is one supposed to help!

Comment: So ... Like I have this program I wrote and like it has some script and stuff in it but I can't seem to get it to work. Can someone tell me like maybe what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("yourId").attr("disabled", true);
```

This should work.